# Get backspace key on iPad keyboard to not only clear the text one by one, but move the cursor to the previous textfield in the UIView

Tags: xcode, ipad, keyboard, backspace

I have 30 UITextfields next to each other on a UIView. Each UITextfield represent a character of a word. A UITextfield allows for one character to be entered before it moves on to the next UITextfield.

I want to use the iPad keyboard 'backspace' to delete the characters, starting from right to left, without moving the cursor with your finger. As you continuously press the backspace button, I want the text of all the UITextfields to be deleted one by one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Use

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Check if the character is backspace, delete the character, and set first responder to the previous text field and return YES.